# Setting a default for a relationship field

Tags: relationships

I have a radio button relationship field that needs to have a default already selected.

Is there a way to set the default selected item for a relationship field?

Comment: Are you open to using JavaScript to accomplish this? Or, no?

Comment: I assumed that this was a feature of relationships. I assumed wrong. I wanted this not in javascript